# Splitting an interger into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, split, integer

I need to split the integer into an array.

For example,

The integer variable `a` equals `48`.

```
a = 48
```

I need to split the 48 into an array based on the count of 10.

I need to get the array as below,

```
arr = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

EDIT:-

I tried following code and it work fine.

```
max = 48
arr = []
j = 0
for i in 1..max
  if i % 10 == 0
    arr[j] = i
    j = j + 1
  end
end

if max % 10 != 0
  arr[j] = max
end

p arr
# => [10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

But if I have a bignum integer it will take more time. Is there any built-in method to this like a split for string.

I know the split method and also I know how to split the string into an array based one the character available in the string. but I don't know how to use the split method splitting the integer into an array based on the count.

Any one please explain me how to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close (and downvoting) this question because it's unclear what's wanted and because the question was changed after answers were posted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I need to delete this question and post the question freshly. How can I delete the question ?

Comment: You cannot delete if there are multiple answers (which there were when you tried to delete) or if there is one upvoted answer (there weren't any when you tried to delete, but now there is one). See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) for additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with `a = 48` then try:

```
(10..a).step(10).to_a.push(a) #=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

Using [`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html#method-i-step) to increment the range by steps of ten before converting to an array and finally appending your value of `a`. Alternatively you can also write:

```
10.step(a,10).to_a << a #=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

Comment: With comparing to all other answers, it executes for the bignum with minimum time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
a = 48
array = []

(1..a/10).each{|x| array.push(x*10)}
a%10 != 0 ? array.push(a) : array

#=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

Comment: I was updated my question. I was tried that concept like looping. But if I have a bignum integer class value, then like this looping takes too much of time. Is there any built-in method or any other way to reduce the time for splitting.

Comment: What you need is a very particular operation. It's hard to imagine that many people would need such thing, and this is the reason why there is no Ruby core method to do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution feel free to change some code mistakes since im not familiar with ruby :

```
$a = 48
$num = 10
array = Array.new

while $num < $a do
   array << $num
   $num +=10
end
array << $a
```

Comment: Your code is working, like PHP, but in ruby we dont use `global` variables this way.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake i said im not familiar with ruby never tried it . thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `lambda` in this case.

```
a = 48
arr = ((1..a/10).map(&->(x){x*10}) << a).uniq

p arr
# => [10, 20, 30, 40, 48]
```

For all elements in Range `(1..a/10)` (in this case `1..4`), map method call lambda function. This lambda have one argument and return `x*10` (for first element `1*10 # => 10`) and add all results to the array.

I hope this helps.